# Junit for stax parser

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, stax

I done parsing for XML using StAX parser..Then now I need to write JUnit test cases for parsing XML. How to write JUnit for those kind of situations? I have code like

```
while( streamReader.hasNext() )
        {
            switch( streamReader.next() )
            {
                case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
                    writeStartElement();
                    break;
                case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT:
                    writeEndElements();
                    break;
                case XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS:
                    writeCharacters();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Now I have three methods `writeStartElement()` for startElements, `writeEndElements()` for endElement and `writeCharacters()` for characters and now I want to write test cases for each method (all methods are void type, return nothing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, extract those 3 methods into a specialized class, a writer and then use as dependency. Then you take advantage of tools like Mockito in order to mock the dependency and verify proper behavior:

**1)** The refactoring:

```
    // the field dependency
    private Writer writer; 

    ....

     switch( streamReader.next() )
        {
            case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
                writer.writeStartElement();
                break;
            case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT:
                writer.writeEndElements();
                break;
            case XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS:
                writer.writeCharacters();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

**2)** Test

```
public class MyTestClass{

   @Mock
   private Writer writerMock;

   @Mock
   private StreamReader streamStub;

   @InjectMocks
   public ClassUnderTest testClass;

   @Before
   public void init(){
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
   }

   // one of three test cases
   @Test
   public void test_START_ELEMENT(){
        // Arrange
        Mockito.when(streamStub.hasNext()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);   
        Mockito.when(streamStub.next()).thenReturn(XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT);

        // Act
        testClass.readStream(streamStub);

        // Assert
        Mockito.verify(times(1), writerMock).writeStartElement();
   }
}
```